# Issues with importing XML Data into Access

Tags: c, xml, perl, ms-access

I'm looking for a way to get XML Data into an Access database. Currently I'm trying to import the files via the XML import tab in Access, but unfortunately this just returns 3 blank tables. This is my first experience with XML, so i'm not too savvy on the standard procedures for getting this type of data into a database. I've read that the files need to go through a "process" before they can be inserted into any database, and this typically requires some programming skills in order to do so. When I've Googled this in the past, I get a lot of articles talking about using Perl to parse the file, but haven't found a lot of concrete examples showing me how to do this.

I guess my questions is, what do I need to do? is there a standard chunk of code I need to create in order to make the files "Access acceptable"? I'm really willing to do anything at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML data is a free-form data type where nodes or elements, attributes, tags can be positioned in any format. As long as markup rules are followed, the design types is limited to only the designer's imagination. Because of this nature, complex XML data must be transformed to fit database's two dimension structure.

Access tables, Excel spreadsheets, CSV files, R data frames, SAS datasets require a tabular format of rows and columns:

```
      Field1 Field2 Field3
row1   data   data   data
row2   data   data   data
```

In XML this equates to:

```
<row1>
   <field1>data</field1>
   <field2>data</field2>
   <field3>data</field3>
</row1>

<row2>
   <field1>data</field1>
   <field2>data</field2>
   <field3>data</field3>
</row2>
```

This is very similar to html tables:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The reason you see blank tables after importing is because the structure of your XML does not adequately align to the two dimensional row and column structure OR XML data resides in attributes and not elements. You may have multiple nested tree structure. Data laid out in elements: `<item>data</item>` and in attributes: `<item attribute="data"></item>`. And still more nuances. NOTE: Access can only import [element-centric](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285329) not attribute-centric xml.

Nearly every programming language (Python, R, PHP, C, C++, C#, Java, Ruby, even Perl and VBA) has a package, module, library, etc. to parse and transform xml files, iterate across nodes to extract data, or other data handler. What you essentially need to do is:

1. Dissect the XML files to assess their overall structure or the
   parts you need
2. Code a transform/parser solution to obtain
       the tabular format of your xml data. I prefer the [xsl transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_editxml.asp)
3. Convert to raw xml to transform xml or csv/txt/xlsx and import into
   Access. In Access VBA you can use:
   [Application.ImportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823157.aspx) and
   [Application.TransformXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844810%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and VBA's general [Load XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384609.aspx).

I hope this helps. Good luck!